# Returning string of a function as an Add-Member value parameter in PowerShell

Tags: function, powershell

I'm trying to create a Powershell script that shows the folder permissions and the members of the permission groups. I have a function called "Get-Members" that returns (as a comma separated string) the members of the group  that has sent to the function as an argument.

Now I'd like to know how i can use the returning string with the Add-Member's value parameter. How can i use the function with that? I tried

```
Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Members" -Value Get-Members($_.IdentityReference) -PassThru
```

but it doesn't seem to be working.

Here's the whole thing:

```
($root | get-acl).Access | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Members" -Value Get-Members($_.IdentityReference) -PassThru  | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Folder" -Value $($root.fullname).ToString()  -PassThru | select -Property Path, IdentityReference, FileSystemRights
```

And here's the function:

```
Function Get-Members {
    param( [string]$group )

    $xyz=$group
    if ($group -match '\\')
    {
        $xyz=$group -creplace '^[^\\]*\\', ''
    }

    $Group = [ADSI]"LDAP://cn=$xyz,ou=SecurityGroups,ou=Accounting,ou=Services,dc=CONTOSO,dc=ny,dc=local"

$Members = $Group.Member | ForEach-Object {[ADSI]"LDAP://$_"}

$combined = $Members | select -ExpandProperty name

$result= $combined -join ","

return $result

}
```

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

Your brackets are wrong. Try this:

```
Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Members" -Value (Get-Members $_.IdentityReference) -PassThru
```

Which would make the Get-Members part execute first and return its values to the `-Value` property due to the brackets.

As an aside, i'd recommend you choose a different name over `Get-Members` because its too close to the very well known `Get-Member` cmdlet.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. For some reason $_.IdentityReference seems to be NULL. I tried both  `-Value (Get-Members $_.IdentityReference)` and `-Value (Get-Members $_.IdentityReference.value)` But it seems that both of them are passing NULL for the function. What could be the cause of this?

Comment: What part of your script is populating `$_`?

Comment: This part: `($root | get-acl).Access` and here's the whole thing:

`($root | get-acl).Access | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Members" -Value (Get-Members $_.IdentityReference) -PassThru `
And `$root = Get-Item $Path`   where $Path is the directory path like "C:\Windows"